# ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 10) vs (None, 11, 2, 2))

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Input:

```
x_train shape: (6000, 16, 16, 1)
x_test shape: (5000, 16, 16, 1)
y_test shape: (5000, 11, 2)
y_test shape: (5000, 16, 16, 1)
6000 train samples
5000 test samples
```

Neural Network :-

```
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 10
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Error:-

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-628ddb8c3023> in <module>()
 ----> 1 hist = model.fit(x_train, 
 y_train,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=1,validation_data=(x_test, 
  y_test))
  2 print("The model has successfully trained")
  3 model.save('mnist.h5')
  4 print("Saving the model as mnist.h5")

   1 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py 
    in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    1127           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    1128             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
```

->      1129               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
1130             else:
1131               raise

```
    ValueError: in user code:
```

I tried my best to explain my problem if there is any confusion then my
apologies, let me know and I will add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, while your model outputs prediction over 10 classes per sample, you passed "true labels" in some non-compatible way, why are your labels  three dimensional? You have a 11x2x2 tensor per sample, instead of a one-hot encoded class number.

Comment: Can you please tell me am I reshaping it correctly?                                                                       `x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 16, 16, 1)
  x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 16, 16, 1)
  input_shape = (16, 16, 1)
  # convert class vectors to binary class matrices
  y_train = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
  y_test = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)`

Comment: I do not know what your data is, but assuming your data is grayscale 16x16 images it looks ok